# Index Seek Query Will Sometimes Take Minutes To Complete

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a query that (~95% of the time) executes nearly instantly on the production Azure SQL Database. Running the query in SSMS (in production) shows that my non-clustered index is being utilized with an index seek (cost 100%).

However, randomly the database all of a sudden gets into a state where this same query will fail to execute. It always times out from the calling application. Logging into SSMS when this episode is occurring I can manually execute the query and it will eventually complete after minutes of execution (since there are no time out limits in SSMS vs that of the calling application).

After I allow the query to fully execute without timeouts I can subsequently execute the query again with instant results. The calling application can also call it now with instant results again. It appears that by allowing it to fully execute without a timeout clears up whatever issue was occurring and returns execution back to normal.

Monitoring the server metrics shows no real issues or spikes in CPU utilization that would suggest the server is just in a stressed state during this time. All other queries within the application still execute quickly as normal. Even queries that utilize this same table and non-clustered index.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item] (
    [Id]             UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [UserId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [Type]           TINYINT          NOT NULL,
    [Data]           NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [CreationDate]   DATETIME2 (7)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Item_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
);
```

This table has millions of rows in it.

**Index**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Item_UserId_Type_IncludeAll]
    ON [dbo].[Item]([UserId] ASC, [Type] ASC)
    INCLUDE ([Data], [CreationDate]);
```

**Issue Query**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [dbo].[Item]
WHERE
    [UserId] = @UserId
    AND [Data] IS NOT NULL
```

While I was catching it in the act today in SSMS, I also modified to query to to remove the `AND [Data] IS NOT NULL` from the where clause. Ex:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [dbo].[Item]
WHERE
    [UserId] = @UserId
```

This query executed instantly and execution plans show that it is utilizing the index properly. Adding back `AND [Data] IS NOT NULL` causes the query be slow again. This `Data` column can hold large amounts of JSON data so I am not sure if that somehow has anything to do with it.

Running `sp_WhoIsActive` while the episode is occurring and my query is long-running shows that `reads`, `physical_reads`, `cpu`, and `used_memory` are ever-increasing as the query continues to execute. Interestingly, the `query_plan` column is NULL while it is running so I am not able to see what plan it is actually utilizing. Though I can always see that the index seek is utilized while running it manually thereafter.

- Why would this query get into a state where it would take a really long time to execute while the majority of the time it executes with near instant results? We can see that it is properly utilizing it's non-clustered index as a seek operation.
- Why does allowing the query to fully execute in SSMS (vs timing out as the calling application does) seem to clear up the problem going forward?
- How can I avoid these types of episodes?

Comment: Maybe the plan is going out of the cache? You can force that specific query to always use an index by adding `WITH(INDEX(IX_Item_UserId_Type_IncludeAll))` after the FROM clause.

Comment: You could try a filtered index, or an index that includes "Data" in the key instead of in an include. But are you sure there are no locking issues going on?

Comment: @JacobH If the plan was out of cache wouldn't I see it not being utilized by other types of queries against it (i.e. removing the `AND [Data] IS NOT NULL` from the WHERE clause as mentioned above)?

Comment: @pmbAustin [Data] contains large amounts of JSON data. I am not sure it would be well suited to be part of the key. How would I see if there are locking issues occurring?

Comment: if you are using `sp_whoisactive`, what does column `wait_info` say?  That should give you some idea.

Comment: Does the query gets slow for certain users that are having large amount of data in [Data] field?

Comment: You can use following query to get a summary of queries where the last execution take longer than a specified amount of time and it shows you the used query plan. 
`select 
     cast(last_elapsed_time as float)/1000000 as duration_s,last_execution_time,execution_count, sq.text, pl.query_plan
from
Sys.dm_exec_query_stats stat
CROSS APPLY Sys.dm_exec_sql_text(stat.sql_handle) sq
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(stat.plan_handle) pl
where
last_execution_time > dateadd(mi, -120, getdate())
and last_elapsed_time > 1000000 -- milli seconds
order by stat.last_elapsed_time desc
`

Comment: You can query the cache to pull the plan out during execution. It may not be available to sp_whoisactive, but it's in cache, it has to be.

However, I'd focus on the wait statistics. Used extended events in Azure SQL DB to capture those along with rpc_starting/completed (or batch_starting/completed). Just make sure you relate the events together so you get a guid and sequence. You then get the waits for the query in action.

Comment: @Greg `wait_info` column was showing `(1ms)PAGEIOLATCH_SH:db_name:1(*)` for this query

Comment: @KashifQureshi I have not noticed it being different per user. Once the episode starts happenings, they query times out the same for everyone calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Few things i would check...

1.Your query doesn't have a good index , a good index would be below since you are doing a select `*` as well as `data is not null`

```
create index nci on table(userid,data)
include(rest of columns in select )
```

2.Try updating statistics and indexes for this table,this will help if there is a index fragmentation or stale statistics

3.Try `option(recompile)` hint to see if parameter sniffing is a problem